# Drag and drop API - OnDragListener issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following:

I have an activity and a fragment acting as a type of navigation drawer (right side).
Inside that drawer fragment I have a grid view.
Currently I am able to long click one of the cells in that grid view which will initiate the startDrag() method. This will create a drag shadow object that I can move around. All according the the API.

After startDrag is called, I call the activity that hosts this fragment using an interface, and ask it to close the drawer. 
So I'm left with the activity and a currently dragged view under my finger.
My problem is, the drop listener. I tried attaching the DragListener to the activity's root view, but none of the actions get called.

Am I missing something? here's the code I use:

This goes in the drawer fragment:

```
mBlocksGridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int     position, long id) {

            // Get the block's id from adapter
            mBlockId = ((BlockItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getBlockId();

            // Get the clicked view
            View clickedView = parent.getChildAt(position);

            // Pass blockId in clipdata
            ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("blockID", String.valueOf(mBlockId));

            // Setup the drag shadow (the bitmap representation of the selected view)
            View.DragShadowBuilder dragShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(clickedView);

            // Start the drag mechanism
            clickedView.startDrag(clipData, dragShadow, clickedView, 0);

            mOnItemSingleClickListener.onBlockItemClickedEvent();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The last call in the ClickListener, mOnItemSingleClickListener.onBlockItemClickedEvent(); calls the activity. This is the code that runs there:

```
@Override
    public void onBlockItemClickedEvent() {

    // check if this is a tablet or not
    if (!_isTablet){

        // it's not, so close the palette
        _twoPaneLayout.hideRight();
    }

    setUpOnDragListener();
}
```

And this is setUpOnDragListener():

```
private void setUpOnDragListener() {
        findViewById(R.id.activity_drawing_viewer_root).setOnDragListener(new MyDragEventListener());
}
```

R.id.activity_drawering_viewer_root is the id of the root view in my activity.

This is the MyDragEventListener class... fairly simple:

```
public class MyDragEventListener implements View.OnDragListener {

// This is the method that the system calls when it dispatches a drag event to the
// listener.
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

    // Defines a variable to store the action type for the incoming event
    final int action = event.getAction();

    // Handles each of the expected events
    switch (action) {

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            Log.d("LOGGY5", "DragStarted");
            return true;

        // Im inside the original view's bounds
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            Log.d("LOGGY5", "We're inside original views bounds");
            return true;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:

            // Ignore the event
            return true;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            Log.d("LOGGY5", "We existed original views bounds");
            return true;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            Log.d("LOGGY5", "We dropped the shadow view" + event.getX() + ":::" + event.getY());
            return true;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            Log.d("LOGGY5", "Drag ended" + event.getX() + ":::" + event.getY());
            return true;

        // An unknown action type was received.
        default:
            Log.e("DragDrop Example", "Unknown action type received by OnDragListener.");
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

The issue is the Drag Listener never gets called... I have to get the X and Y coords of the drag shadow in the activity so once its dropped, I can call another method that will place the dragged item inside the layout using the correct X,Y coords...

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the problem... The DragListener returned false which effectively passed the event down the chain and did not consume it himself.

Changed it to true and the listener became active.

First paragraph [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnDragListener.html). Explains it.